# Is there a way to track from which window.name a new window was opened (open in a new tab) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

I need to track all users browser activity from a starting point. All starting points have unique `window.name` assigned to them.

If a user clicks open in a new tab, I will lose this unique identifier to actually track each starting point. I need to find a somewhere an association between these two windows (the child and the parent window from which the child was triggered).

Can the "open in a new tab" be handled as an event so I can attach an event listener? Or what other solutions are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've clarified your question in the comments below. You're asking specifically about the **user** right-clicking a link and choosing "Open in new tab." (As opposed to the user clicking links that *you've* set up to open in new tabs, which is how I read it originally.)

The simplest and most reliable way to do that is to modify the links on the page to pass the window name as a query string parameter:

```
var i, list, href;
list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    href = list[i].href;
    if (href.indexOf("?") === -1) {
        href += "?wnd=" + encodeURIComponent(window.name);
    }
    else {
        href += "&wnd=" + encodeURIComponent(window.name);
    }
}
```

Then the target page just checks for the query string parameter in `location.search`.

Alternately, you can set some information in [web session storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) when the user clicks the link, and then check for it on the target page:

On the first page:

```
var i, list;
list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", setWindowName, false);
    // If you need to handle IE8, you'll need to do the addEventListener / attachEvent dance
}
function setWindowName() {
    sessionStorage.wndname = window.name;
}
```

Then on the target page:

```
var sourceWindow = sessionStorage.wndname;
```

Other than that, you can give them a link that will open the window in a new tab for them (see below), but if *they* right-click the link and say "open in new tab," I don't think there's any connection between the two windows. On the **server** side you could check the REFERER [sic] HTTP header, but I don't think there's anything purely client-side.

> Can i handle "open in a new tab" as an event...

I don't believe any event is raised when the user opens a link in a new window or tab.

---

If the window is opened via `window.open` or a link with `target="..."`, the new window will have an `opener` global, which is a reference to the window that opened it. So, `opener.name`.

Parent window example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/IBuCOVo/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/IBuCOVo/1/edit)

```
window.name = "parentwin";
document.querySelector('p').onclick = function() {
    window.open("/uTEzowOQ/1");
};
```

Or alternately via a link: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/IBuCOVo/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/IBuCOVo/2/edit)

```
<p><a href="/uTEzowOQ/1" target="_blank">Click me</a></p>
<script>
window.name = "parentwin";
</script>
```

Child window: [Source](http://jsbin.com/uTEzowOQ/1/edit)

```
if (!opener) {
    display("My <code>opener</code> isn't set.");
}
else if (!opener.name) {
    display("<code>opener.name</code> is blank");
}
else {
    display("My opener's name is " + opener.name);
}
```

Note that if you just go [directly to the child page](http://jsbin.com/uTEzowOQ/1), it says "My opener isn't set". But if you go there via either of the parent pages above, you see "My opener's name is parentwin".

Comment: I know about window.open , the question was about clicking "open in a new tab" . Does the "open in a new tab" trigger window.open ? Can it be handled as an event?

Comment: @GeoC.: It's up to the browser whether `window.open` occurs in a new tab or a new window. You can give it hints, but the browser makes the decision.

Comment: @GeoC.: I've revised the answer a bit, I made it seem like it *had* to be opened via `window.open`, but it doesn't. A link with a `target` works just as well.

Comment: You did not understand my quention/comment . I know a tab is a window . Window.open js method and click on "open in a new tab" trigger the same thing ? Can i get opener.name if the user click "open in a new tab/window" ?

Comment: @GeoC.: I don't think you can, no. You can give them a link that does that (see above), but if they right-click the link and say "open in new tab," I don't think there's any connection between the two. On the server side you could check the `referer` [sic] HTTP header, but I don't think there's anything purely client-side.

Comment: That's what my question was about clicking "open in a new tab" . Even if i can't get the opener.name. Can i handle "open in a new tab" as an event so i know when it's triggered . So after i could store a cookie for the parent window and after that the imediate child will hold a reference to that cookie .

Comment: @GeoC.: I've updated the answer again, with what I think is your best option.

Comment: I can't use query params because i'm using jsonp (i'm not allowed by owners to alter the query strings) . I have checked all the other opetions there and the only one that was possibe for my case was manipulation of window names . Thanks for the effort +1 . I think i will handle the clicks events and store info in cookies for the next opend window without a name from the same domain . Thought there was a simpler solution .

Comment: @GeoC.: I'm not following you about JSONP. Users don't open JSONP files directly, so what does the query string of the JSONP URL have to do with the query string of *your* pages? Separately: I added a non-query-string option above.

Comment: Ok nevermind the jsonp it's much too complicated to write in a comment . Thank you for your answer it was helpfull , i will validate this answer in 1-2 days . P.S. i think session storage is not a standard .

Comment: Nevermind i will accept it now . I guess there aren't any browser built in sollutions regarding the association of 2 windows (for my "open in a new tab" case) . Ty again